# How to generate a Checkboxes grid with Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, checkbox, datagridview

Does somebody know how to programmatically generate a grid of checkboxes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD1sr.jpg) using a 2D Array?

```
for (int x = 0; x < numberOfRows; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfColumns; y++)
    {
        int index = x * numberOfColumns + y;
        var checkbox = new CheckBox();

        checkbox.Location = new Point(20 * x, 20*y);
        this.Controls.Add(checkbox);
    }
}
```

Comment: `CheckBox[,] c = new CheckBox[10,10];
         
            for (int i = 0; i < c.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < c.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    c[i,j] = new CheckBox();
                    c[i, j].Location = new Point(5, i * 20);
                    this.Controls.Add(c[i, j]);
                }
            }`

Comment: Are you using WPF ?

Comment: No just Windows Form

Comment: Have you considered a `DataGridView` full of checkbox columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the Answer the Problem was the Autosize without Autosize=true some Checkboxes will not be visible

```
     CheckBox[,] c = new CheckBox[2, 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < c.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < c.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                c[i, j] = new CheckBox();
                c[i, j].Location = new Point(i*20, j* 20);

                   c[i, j].AutoSize = true;

                //c[i, j].Height = 10;
                //c[i, j].Width = 10;
                this.Controls.Add(c[i, j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. You need to initialise a dictionary, as shown here at the top, to allow for the GetCheckBoxAtPosition function to work.

```
    private Dictionary<Point, CheckBox> checkBoxes;

    private Dictionary<Point,CheckBox> GenerateCheckBoxes(Form form, int width, int height, int padding) {

        Dictionary<Point, CheckBox> checkboxes = new Dictionary<Point, CheckBox>();

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                Point location = new Point(x*(15+padding), y*(15+padding));

                //Formatting
                checkBox.Location = location;
                checkBox.Text = string.Empty;
                checkBox.Size = new Size(15,15);

                //Custom behaviour
                checkBox.Click += CheckBox_Click;

                form.Controls.Add(checkBox);
                checkboxes.Add(new Point(x, y), checkBox);                                 
            }
        }

        return checkboxes;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox clicked = (CheckBox)sender;
    }

    private CheckBox GetCheckBoxAtPosition(int x, int y) {
        return checkBoxes[new Point(x, y)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a List of Lists, like this:

```
private List<List<CheckBox>> CheckBoxes = new List<List<CheckBox>>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfRows = 5;
    int numberOfColumns = 10;

    CheckBoxes.Clear();
    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfRows; y++)
    {
        List<CheckBox> row = new List<CheckBox>();
        CheckBoxes.Add(row);
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfColumns; x++)
        {
            var checkbox = new CheckBox();
            checkbox.Text = "";
            checkbox.AutoSize = true;
            checkbox.Location = new Point(20 * x, 20 * y);
            row.Add(checkbox);
            this.Controls.Add(checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could access a particular one with:

```
CheckBoxes[0][3].Checked = true;
```